# Laravel mix, faster sass compilation with many ouput files

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass, laravel-mix

**Context:**

Hi, I am working on a website with a lot of reusable blocks each of which have a separate scss & js file.

In order to optimize performances, I've configured mix to output css in separated files so I can load them only if the corresponding block is present on the current page.

This is fine, except mix take more than 40 seconds to recompile now (instead of  6 seconds for a single output file) and this is slowing my work quite a bit...

**Question:**

How can I make mix compile faster in this situation, is it possible to recompile only the modified files ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `version()` object? I think you can cache the version when this is not changing.

This is a very basic example and hope it helps.

```
/*
* JS
* */
mix.setResourceRoot('/public/assets/admin/')
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/assets/admin/')
    .version();
/*
* Styles
* */
mix.styles([
    'public/assets/admin/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    'public/assets/admin/css/style.min.css',
], 'public/assets/admin/app.css');
mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/assets/admin/app.css').options({
        postCss: [
            require('autoprefixer'),
        ],
    }).version();
```